# finding out thread information

Tags: multithreading, process, procfs

I have a list of processes running in my system and the threads belonging to these processes. I want to know if there is anyway to get the complete information about a specific thread, for example: priority, function it executes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is exactly what you want but I used this for an operating systems class I took last year.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/get-detailed-information-about-process-threads-with-processthreadsview/

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux you can read process specific information out of `/proc/<pid>`.

To do so [libproc](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) might help.